# Where do I put a procedural code snippet to run in PHP.Gt?

Tags: php, email, email-validation, php.gt

I've saved the code from this tutorial: http://myphpform.com/final-form.php which should send an email when the form submits.

I'd like to use it in a simple Contact page. Here's the markup:

```
<main role="content">
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Contact</h1>
        </header>
        <section role="contact-us">
            <form action="/Script/contact.php" method="post">
                <label for="name">Full name</label>
                <input type="text" name="yourname" placeholder="Name..." id="name">
                <label for="email" name="email">Email address</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="you@email.com" id="email">
                <textarea placeholder="Your comments..." rows ="5" name="comment-text" name="comments"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" name="submit">
            </form>
        </section>
    </section>
</main>
```

Where should the PHP go, and does it need converting in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add code to your PHP.Gt application, you use a Page Logic object in PHP.Gt. Page Logic is PHP that is executed in context of a particular page, and provides an object-oriented entrance point to your page's code.

The code in the link you supplied uses procedural PHP, so will need to be put into a class in order to be used.

As a side note, your HTML form does not need to have anything in the `action` attribute. Without the action attribute, it will post to the current page, which is where your logic will lie.

Assuming your current markup lies at `src/Page/contact.html`, create a PHP file at `/src/Page/contact.php` and add the bare-bones Page Logic class below:

```
<?php
namespace App\Page;

class Contact extends \Gt\Page\Logic {

public function go() {
}

}#
```

An explanation to the link between HTML files (Page Views) and PHP code (Page Logic) is available in the documentation: https://github.com/BrightFlair/PHP.Gt/wiki/Pages

---

Any logic that is placed in the `go()` method will be executed before the page is rendered, so this is exactly where you need to place the email script from the link you posted.

There will be a bit of manipulation to the code required to make it object-oriented, but here's a simplified example of what you're trying to achieve:

`go() {`

```
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    // If the form isn't submitted, do not continue.
    return;
}

mail("your-email@example.com", "Contact form message", $_POST["comment-text"]);
header('Location: /thanks');
```

`}`

The functions posted in the procedural example can simply be attached to the Logic object as private methods, although I would take this opportunity to update them using proper validation techniques such as the native [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function.

The `show_error` function in the example echoes HTML from PHP, which is against the strong [separation of concerns](https://github.com/BrightFlair/PHP.Gt/wiki/Quick-Start#separation-of-concerns) enforced by PHP.Gt, but the [Hello, you tutorial](https://github.com/BrightFlair/PHP.Gt/wiki/hello-you-tutorial) shows how content on the page can be manipulated using Page Logic - this is how you can output an error message within the `show_error` method.